# Can a maximum value of a function be an unbiased estimator?

Tags: unbiased-estimator, order-statistics

Given a probability density function f(y) = 2y/(Θ^2) for 0≤y≤Θ, and given Y(n) is the maximum value in the sample, the problem is to determine if Y(n) is an unbiased estimator of Θ.
My initial approach was to determine whether E(Y(n))= Θ.
However, this did not make much sense to me intuitively; since E(Y(n)) is always a function of n and Θ, and n≥1, is it ever possible for E(Y(n)) to equal to Θ.

My query is given a function y which includes some parameter Θ, whether the maximum or the minimum value of Y could ever be an unbiased estimator of Θ, and what would be the correct approach to determine this in this example.

Comment: Also, in your example, you can verify that $ E(Y_n) = (2n/(2n+1)) \cdot \Theta $

Comment: For the general case: If you have an estimator that can under-estimate the true value, but can never over-estimate it, it's not unbiased. And in your case, $Y_n$ could never be more than $\Theta$ (it can only reach $\Theta$ asymptotically from below), only less than $\Theta$; that makes it biased.

Comment: Nevertheless, the maximum value of a function of a random sample can be unbiased. Take, for instance, $(2n Y(n))/(2n+1),$ whose expectation is $\theta.$